# Is it ok to create a small pixmap on the stack like this?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a small painting application and I want to make a chess-like background in order to represent transparency. As I'm new with Qt and C++, I was wondering if is it ok (performance/memory) to create a small pixmap in the stack like this:

```
void GraphicsScene::drawBackground (QPainter *painter, const QRectF&)
{
    QPixmap pix(16, 16);
    QPainter p(&pix);
    p.fillRect(0, 0, 8, 8, Qt::white);
    p.fillRect(8, 0, 8, 8, Qt::gray);
    p.fillRect(0, 8, 8, 8, Qt::gray);
    p.fillRect(8, 8, 8, 8, Qt::white);
    QBrush b(pix);
    painter->fillRect(sceneRect(), b);
}
```

Or better I create the brush once and store it in a member field?

Comment: Depends on how often you need to call `drawBackground()`

Answer (score 0):

If it is a constant and immutable, I would create it as a `static const` somewhere or a `static` that is lazily initialized using `std::call_once` or similar guard.

That might be premature optimization, but I would refactor it into a free function at the very least.  If you do see a performance issue in the future, you can employ memoization to optimize without having to refactor all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

As your code seems to be readable and correct, I would suggest that you do not change it. Postpone optimization up until it is proven that performance is important for this particular function (using a profiler, for example).

Currently, you are not doing anything particularly ineffective; objects of this size are welcome on the stack.